# No data found error even though data exists

Tags: oracle

The problem I'm having is similar to that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401785/oracle-no-data-found-but-data-exists) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896143/ora-01403-no-data-found-error), but in those cases there was a char vs varchar issue.

I'm trying to select the first partition for my table from user_tab_partitions; I've tried it two ways:

```
SELECT partition_name, high_value into V_PARTITION_NAME, V_HIGH_VALUE from user_tab_partitions where table_name like 'MYTABLE' and partition_position=1;

SELECT partition_name, high_value into V_PARTITION_NAME, V_HIGH_VALUE from user_tab_partitions where table_name like 'MYTABLE' and rownum<=1 order by partition_position;
```

Either way, the code works fine in SQL Developer but when I run it as part of a stored procedure, I get the NO_DATA_FOUND exception. There's a check prior to this code that ensures it doesn't run unless at least two partitions exist.

Comment: Is the procedure owned by the same user that is running the queries in SQL Developer?  Are you really using `user_tab_partitions` rather than `all_tab_partitions` or `dba_tab_partitions`?  Frequently, people have this problem with the `all_` or `dba_` versions of data dictionary tables when your access to objects is via a role since privileges granted via roles aren't available to definer's rights stored procedures.

Comment: Hmmm...I switched from all_tab_partitions to user_tab_partitions to avoid having to check that the owner is equal to the current user, but I'll try switching it back and see if it makes a difference.  Best idea I've heard so far.

Comment: Looks like that was it; switching to all_tab_partitions resolved my issue. Thanks! Do you want to make your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Comment: So then is the owner of the procedure different than the user that is running the query in SQL Developer?  Or is the procedure an invoker's rights procedure that is being called by a different user?  I'm not clear on why switching to `all_tab_partitions` would fix the issue you have in your procedure.

Comment: I need to check, but I strongly suspect that the driving code called my procedure with another user with fewer permissions instead of the owner. I'm not entirely certain why another select against the same table worked, though.